# Post apocalypse young adult fiction

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

Trying to remember a book I read in grade school (published prior to 2005).  It follows a group of kids that were saved from a nuclear holocaust by being placed in stasis.  The mutated man that let them out of stasis is the boys father.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Andrew! Make sure you've visited the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. Also, take a look at this [Story-ID guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) to jog your memory and [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/163265/edit) any more details you might have missed out.

Answer (score 1):

This has a familiar ring.

This could be *Flight of the Eagles* by Gilbert L. Morris, the first book in the Seven Sleepers series.

The book had some strong christian and anti-semitic tones. The nuclear holocaust had released things from inside the earth and completely changed the geography and people of the Earth. The main villains were the Sanhedrin and the group traveled to various locations, including Atlantis and Camelot, getting help to stop them.